# How to Obtain Users ID and Put it in a Table

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, navicat

I'm trying to make a football betting system based on the **WordPress** CMS. I apologize if this is a redundant question, but I've been searching through Google and a few Wiki's all day, and I haven't been able to find any clue to how this question is answered.

**BACKGROUND INFORMATION:**

I use:

- MySQL
- PHP
- Navicat

Every time the user inputs two integers, corresponding to the goalscorings in a football match, on the php-scripted website, the two integers get sent off to the database table "bets", through an **insert.php**-file.

**The insert.php looks like this:**

```
<?php $con = mysql_connect("host","username","password"); if (!$con)   {   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());   }

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO bets (homebet, awaybet) VALUES ('$_POST[homebet]','$_POST[awaybet]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))   {   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());   } echo "Thanks for betting!";

mysql_close($con); ?>
```

**The php-form looks like this:**

[image]

I have the following self-made tables: **bets**, **teams**, **matches**, and I have the WordPress table, **wp-users**, where each member is listed.

**The bets table looks like this:**
[image: each row corresponds to a new bet]

As you can see, the userid is empty - which it shouldn't be. It should contain the ID of the user, who entered the bet.

**My two-part question is then..**

How should I obtain the ID of the user and display it in the database table, *bets*? Perhaps WordPress have a code-snippet for it.

And finally, how should I attach a **gameid** to each match? Should I create a new *form* for each new match?

Thanks *SO* much in advance - I hope I was able to make this thread readable and easy to understand.

Frederick Andersen

Comment: Stop using the legacy mysql_ functions. Start using mysqli/PDO.

Comment: clentfort, even though Wordpress itself uses the mysql_ library? Why should people mix different db libraries in the same project?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't make any sence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quite some things here. I can't advise you how to manage the different games since I don't know what the rest of your application looks like.

Here are some pointers to get you going:

**Don't create your own DB connection**

Remove:

```
$con = mysql_connect("host","username","password"); if (!$con)   {   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());   }

mysql_select_db("database", $con);
```

Add instead:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
```

**WordPress current user ID**

Add this to top off script:

```
global $wpdb, $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
```

Change $sql code to this:

```
$sql= $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO `bets` (`userid`, `homebet`, `awaybet`) VALUES (%d, %d, %d)", $current_user->ID, $_POST['homebet'], $_POST['awaybet']);
```

I've also used the wpdb prepare function so your post data will be escaped before getting queried.

Also change this to use WP native querying.

Remove:

```
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))   {   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());   } echo "Thanks for betting!";

mysql_close($con);
```

Add instead:

```
$wpdb->query($sql)
```

Comment: Thanks, Barry! It returns an error on execution, though:
Fatal error:`Call to undefined function get_currentuserinfo() in /var/www/fredrixdesign.com/betting-scout/scripts/insert.php on line 3`
Line 3 is `get_currentuserinfo();`

Comment: You're sure you included "require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');", or is your WordPress installation in a sub directory? It looks like you don't have WordPress included.

Comment: The WordPress is in a subdomain. The subdomain is named "bs". And "require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');" should be after "global $wpdb, $current_user; get_currentuserinfo();", right?

Comment: Change it to "require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bs/wp-load.php');" and please put it at the absolute top of the file!

Comment: Great. The process works now. It adds it to the database just like before, but it still doesn't add any value under userid.

Comment: You're sure there is a logged in user? `var_dump` the `$current_user` after the `get_currentuserinfo();`

Comment: You're awesome, Barry! That does the trick - logging in ;)
Could you possibly help me out with my **gameid** problem as well?

Comment: I can imagine you've got your games in a different table. `SQL SELECT` them from that table and put them in a `<select>` in your php-form. This way that value also gets posted to your insert.php file. Now in your insert.php just add it to the `INSERT` query.

Comment: How would I declare a gameid to each `<select>` in the `<form>`? I can't really figure this out.